# Reading all directories from a text file

Tags: perl

I have a text file called `paths.txt` that contains file system paths like below

```
/prod/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/empstmt/parm/
/prod/bcs/hdpp/clientapp/trprpsp/parm/
/prod/bcs/hdpp/clientapp/trpnonq/parm/
/prod/bcs/lgnp/clientapp/kmpndwl/parm/
```

I am trying to read all the data present in those directories using Perl.

I tried like this, but it's unable to open the directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my ($path, $file, @files);

open(IN, "paths.txt");

foreach $path ( <IN> ) {

    opendir(DIR, $path) or die "Cannot open $path\n";

    while ( $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
        print "$file";
    }

    closedir(DIR);
}

close(IN);
```

Comment: Don't use `-w`; use `use warnings;` instead. Don't predeclare variables; declare them on first use. Don't use 2-arg open, use 3-arg open. Don't use bareword filehandles, just use normal variables.

Comment: Check for `open` failure. Include `$!` in the error message for `open` and `opendir`.

Comment: Why are you slurping in all of `paths.txt` (with that `foreach` / `readline` loop) but reading directory entries one at a time (`while` / `readdir`)?

Comment: `... or die "$0: Cannot open $path: $!\n";` would have probably told you what the problem is.

Comment: Remember that your file of paths has a end of line char at the end of each path. you need to use chomp to remove that other wise you wil be essentially trying to open a dir called "/some/dir/\n"